# PhoneGap in regards to App Store approval

Tags: ios, cordova, store

I read that PhoneGap is approved by Apple as a framework for building native apps, but I'm not clear on how this does not constitute a "website wrapped as an app," something that Apple specifically doesn't like, as per their App Store guidelines. I'm assuming it is because the JS is contained in the application, rather than running on a remote server?

Any clarification on this issue would be most appreciated.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

> but I'm not clear on how this does not constitute a "website wrapped
>   as an app," something that Apple specifically doesn't like, as per
>   their App Store guidelines.

By this Apple means Apps that simply show a UIWebView that loads a remote website, so it basically just behaves like Mobile Safari, just without the controls. Also they wan't Apps to show at least a UI when the device is not connected to the internet, like in the Facebook App where you can still read already downloaded status updates, view photos etc. That's what a "I just wrap a remote website inside a UIWebView"-App can't do.

PhoneGap Apps have all the resources they need (HTML, CSS, JavaScript) on the device residing in the App's bundle, so using such an App would not depend on network availability and could at least show a UI that tells you to connect to the Internet in order to use the App, or they could display already loaded content (like Facebook, Twitter and so on).

Comment: Thanks. So, as I understand it, having a PhoneGap app that contains all the UI in the bundle, requests data from a server (i.e. JSON) and parses it for display to the user does not constitute what Apple calls a "website wrapped as an app." Am I correct in thinking this?

Comment: Yes, that's right. But also never forget to display a message to the user that says "Hey, I need internet, but you're not connected. Please connect to the internet to use the App". That's what we're doing in a live App that is in the store for almost over 2 years now. Just make sure your App does not break apart and crashes when there is no internet connection :-)

Answer (score 0):

I think that the signature of the binary tells Apple what framework built the application, and since all the supporting files (js included) are included in the project and therefore in the binary, it is a standalone application.  That being said, I still think that doing things Natively is the best way to go.  I am extremely comfortable with javascript and started out thinking Phonegap was the way to go for me.  I did a couple of projects with it and then decided to take the plunge and learn Objective-C.  That worked out so much better for me.  No dependency on a third party framework and I wish that I had started that way.

Sometimes the easy way out just hurts ya in the end IMO.

Comment: Plus you can never tell when Apple will change the rules and decide Phonegap isn't allowed.

Comment: Thanks for the quick reply. I would write it in Obj-C but the timeframe for the project doesn't allow me this privilege – JavaScript would be much faster for me. I researched it a bit more and I think if I keep all of the "controller" inside the app with the data being loaded from a server, I think Apple is okay with that. After all, they do say that JavaScript is one of the languages that you can use to build apps, along with C, C++, and Objective-C.

Comment: I think you can still load data from a server, as long as you do the normal handling of no data available.  In other words the application should still work and not crash when an Internet connection isn't available.

Comment: Thanks for the help. I'm going to build the app so that the UI lives on the device in the app bundle which will load JSON data from the server.